# Use an amazon ECR image from one account in the codebuild of another account

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have a docker image in a central account's ECR in Amazon AWS that I want to use in multiple sub-accounts CodePipeline builds as the build environment, is there a way I can grant the CodeBuild service on these accounts access to this private ECR repository and images using IAM permissions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found my answer after some more careful googling https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=244603 https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=828128&tstart=0

Basically the way I wanted to manage docker images and builds is not yet supported.

Comment: Support for cross-account ECR images in AWS CodeBuild was announced on 2019-01-24: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/01/aws-codebuild-now-supports-accessing-cross-account-ecr-images/